# drag and drop different rows within a group in jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have a table with many rows with different categories like :

```
Mobile
    nokia
    samsung
        grand-1
        grand-2
    Apple
Car
Computer
    Apple
    Intel
Mouse
```

We have categories like Mobile, Car, computer and mouse and I want to drag and drop the elements but within its group only like we can drag and drop grand-1 to grand-2 but not under nokia or computer. but whole samsung group can be drag instead of nokia or apple.

Similarly Car and Mobile can be drag and drop with each other along with all inner categories.

I have used some jQuery libraries and tablednd plugin but I can drag each row anywhere since each item has a different  in the table.

Is there any solutions? any help would be appreciated.

I am using following subroutine in perl.

```
sub mainList {

    my $hash = shift;
    my $options = '';
    my $iter;
    $options .= "<table id='sort' class='grid' >
                 <tbody>";  
    $iter = sub {
        my $hash = shift;       
        my $indent = shift || '';
        my $count = 0;
        foreach my $k (sort keys %{$hash}) {                    
            my $v = $hash->{$k};
            $options .= "<tr><td>$v->{title}<br><" unless $indent;          
            if($indent){
                $options .= "$v->{title} $indent";          
            }                       
            if ($v->{children}){
                $iter->($v->{children}, "--");
            }

            $options .= "</td></tr>" unless $indent;                
        }

    };
    $iter->($hash);
    $options .="</tbody></table>";
    return $options;
}
```

where I am passing a hash ref to create the table.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to use separate tables, 1 for each group. You may have to mess with the CSS margin, border to get the tables to look like 1 seamless table if that's what your after.

```
<table><caption>Mobile</caption>
<tr>
<td>nokia</td>
<td>samesung</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table><caption>Computer</caption>
<tr>
<td>apple</td>
<td>intel</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion but table is creating dynamically through a function.

Comment: @ABHISHEKGOYAL - I'm sure the function that creates the table can be easily modified to create multiple tables instead. If you want to share the function's code someone else or myself could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery-ui, it has option to drop only to the certain elements